# Travel or travel to?

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say you are reporting a survey about British travel. Which one of these should I use?

> Britons visits (year 1999)

- In France: 7500
- in Spain: 400
- In turkey: 200

> It is clear that the proportion of tours abroad increased. Whereas, while Britons most **travelled to** country was France, the least **visited to** nation was Turkey for citizens of the United Kingdom.

Or

> It is clear that the proportion of tours abroad increased. Whereas, while Britons most **travelled** country was France, the least **visited** nation was Turkey for citizens of the United Kingdom.

Should I use "travel to" or just "travel"? Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in any language, when you find yourself up against a choice between two awkward phrasings, it might be better to reorganize the entire sentence.  Also keep in mind the style principle of *parallelism*, meaning that it's better to use the same structure for both parts of a comparison:

> The country Britons **visited the most** was France, and the country they **visited the least** was Turkey.

If you feel you really must use "traveled to", again, use it in both parts of the comparison:

> The country Britons **traveled to** the most was France, and the country they **traveled to** the least was Turkey.

Or, reducing further:

> Britons **traveled** to France most often, and (traveled to) Turkey least often.

I think you'd have to have a "to" somewhere in the sentence, although it doesn't have to be adjacent to "traveled":

> The country **to which** Britons **traveled** most is France, and (the country to which they traveled) least is Turkey ...

Personally, I think shorter is better, but as always this depends on context.  Sometimes a longer sentence creates the right emphasis, or counterpoints another sentence.

Note:  Use either "Britons" or "people from the UK", but not both in the same sentence as it's redundant.  Plus, as Brad mentions in the other answer, [these are not necessarily equivalent](https://brilliantmaps.com/eng-gb-uk/) since "the UK" is not the same as "Great Britain".

Comment: I have put in "parallelism" throughout, so I suppose that advice is irrelevant. The people **from** the UK is so much appreciated, cause mine is "**for** citizens **of** the United Kingdom" (I think mine is ungrammatical). Should be **for-->by**, and **of-->from**

Comment: @JohnArvin  "citizens of the United Kingdom" is fine, I was just paraphrasing.   There's nothing wrong with, *"The country citizens of the UK traveled to the most is ..."*

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have got a lot of things wrong here.

Firstly you talk about Britons and then quote numbers for UK visitors. 
Britons are people from the British Isles which includes Ireland, Eire being a country separate from the UK the figures would be false.

> Briton; noun; a person from Britain:**[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/briton?q=Brito)**
>
> Six Britons are believed to have been involved in the accident.
>
> The book examines the life of the Ancient Britons before the coming of the Romans.

Secondly The choice of the word **Britons** is not a good one. Reading your question. thoughts of Boadicea with her chariot full of duty free Brandy being chased by some Roman centurions, immediately sprang to mind. Today we would normally be referred to as **British or Irish** dependant on our country of origin.

> **British**; adjective: belonging to or relating to the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland or its people:
>
> **Éire;** noun, the name for Ireland in Irish [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eire?q=Eir)

Third; your list

> Britons visits (year 1999)
>
> In France: 7500
>
> in Spain: 400

should be replaced with

British & Irish visitors/tourists (year 1999)

France: 7500

Spain: 400

> It is clear that the proportion of tours abroad increased. Whereas, while Britons most travelled to country was France, the least visited to nation was Turkey for citizens of the United Kingdom
>
> It is clear that the proportion of tours abroad increased. Whereas, while Britons most travelled to country was France, the least visited to nation was Turkey for citizens of the United Kingdom

It is clear that the proportion of British & Irish overseas tours increased during ( Time period needed here). The most travelled to country was France whilst the least visited **of the most visited tourist destinations** was Turkey.

Again you have not referenced the time period. You must reference a time or the statement is false

**whilst the least visited** This has to be referenced as I am sure that there were places (Pitcairn island for example) that had less visitors than Turkey. Therefore it would be a false statement. I have made an example reference, but I would not suggest that this is the correct one to use in this case.

So **to answer your question** we should used **Travelled** **to** as in your first example and **Visited** as in your second example

> It is clear that the proportion of tours abroad increased. Whereas, while Britons most travelled to country was France, the least visited to nation was Turkey for citizens of the United Kingdom.

Or

> It is clear that the proportion of tours abroad increased. Whereas, while Britons most travelled country was France, the least visited nation was Turkey for citizens of the United Kingdom.

**Note The use of Britons**, **My Opinion and the facts**
In my opinion the two versions of Briton Modern and Ancient are both slued in favour of political agendas. Modern Britons include people from British Overseas Territories and Dependant Colonies.  Whilst. Today’s references to Ancient Britons has no boundaries with them quoted as having being present in England, France, Scotland, Spain and Wales however they have mysteriously vanished from Ireland. Reference any historical text on Hibernia and you will find that the Scots were a significant tribe in this area. In what is now modern day Scotland the ancient people are reference as Britons, but in modern texts the Scots of Ireland are no longer Britons. Also the Irish Language is of Celtic origin. The main defining point of all the definition of the Ancient Britons quotes the use of a common/similar language. Therefore unless politically motivated I see no reason why Britons have now been removed from the second largest of the British Isles. Similarly why have some dictionaries and other reference sources now swallowed up Northern Ireland and included it in with Great Britain. Ireland and hence Northern Ireland are separate from Great Britain. Even my passport says Citizen of Great Britain and Northern Ireland.  But then, there is nothing new about political deception committed by the literati My Great Grandfather’s copy of the King James Bible Proclaimed Him King (James) of England, Scotland, Ireland and France.

Comment: The history and correct use of the word "briton" is outstanding but you did not answer my only question. Anyway, thx.

Comment: Sorry John I thought I had in my re-written conclusion I have put "Travelled to" and "visited" I will however edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: The bit about Britons is a little incorrect.  Formally it means a person from Great Britain (not from Ireland, though somtimes Northern Irish might include themselves). Also, don't use "Eire" unless you are speaking Irish. The offical name of the country in English is "Ireland".  You can say "Republic of Ireland" if you need to emphasise "not the North".

Comment: @James K On the first point you are correct I should have used the Republic of Ireland. On the second point I am afraid we are both victims of political bias yet again. The two versions of Briton Modern and Ancient are both slued in favour of political agendas. Modern Britons include people from British Overseas Territories and Dependant Colonies. Whilst. Today’s references to Ancient Britons has no boundaries with them quoted as being present in England, France, Scotland, Spain and Wales however they have mysteriously vanished into the Irish Fog  But  their foot prints still remain.

Comment: @Brad  I'm going to have to go with James K on this one.  The use of "Britons" to mean "people from the UK" is widespread, even if it may be technically incorrect.  I suggest editing your answer to avoid future downvotes.

Comment: @Brad  I often add "side notes" after an answer to address issues like this.  It should be fine to state your opinion, but it's important to label it as such, unless you can provide supporting references.